# How to convert or import or integrate pst, dbx and mbox to a mail server?

Tags: email, thunderbird, dovecot

I have a few mail archives in the Outlook .pst, Outlook Express .dbx, and Thunderbird mbox formats. I would like to consolidate them into a POP3/IMAP server like Dovecot.

The goal is to consolidate them in a server and view them via IMAP from a mobile app.

- How to import these archive mails into Dovecot?
- If import is not available, any other method to get these archive mails and attachment into Dovecot?
- Is there a step-by-step tutorial on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As Dovecot supports the mbox format, you can use [`doveadm import`](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Import) to copy mails from this mailstore. The example from the linked manual page is rather comprehensive:

```
doveadm import -u jane.doe@example.org \
mdbox:/backup/20101026/jane.doe/mdbox backup-20101026 all
```

Dovecot does *not* support the mailstores of Outlook and Outlook Express. Before considering [complicated and error-prone conversion methods to mbox or maildir archives](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files), I'd recommend importing them in a running version of the respective software, and simply copying the mails back to the server via IMAP. This might even be the easier solution for the Thunderbird archives.

Comment: Are you suggesting to setup DoveCot server, get imap working, then just copy mails from these archived mailbox into it?

Comment: Yes, this is very likely the easiest way, as long as you're talking about dozens (or more) mailboxes and want to automate the process.

Comment: FYI, still working on it. Will come back with details if it work.